# ESQL in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-sql

Is there any good and, if possible, exhaustive documentation about ESQL in entity framework ?

I'm trying to make a `select` of an entity object with modification of a property using a method; something like this :

```
SELECT foo FROM context.foo WHERE foo.Price = AddTaxes(foo.Price)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is msdn providing some documentation [Entity SQL Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399560.aspx)

You can also combine it with Linq2Entities with something like

```
context.foo
    .Where("it.Price == @Price", new ObjectParameter[] 
    { new ObjectParameter("Price", AddTaxes(price) } ).ToList()
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer but from where come the price object in your query ?

Comment: where does the it.Price come from? I'm trying `from p in context.Players.Where("p.Name like '@playerNameLike'",  new ObjectParameter[]{new ObjectParameter("playerNameLike", playerNameLike)})` ?

Comment: @Maslow it is the default name for the current instance so it.Price is the current instance of foo.Price

Comment: To me, the real question is what is context.foo?  If I generate an EDMX from a database, I get a DbContext with DbSets for each table I imported, and the Sets have a number of "Where()" methods available, but they take Funcs or Expressions as parameters, not strings. And if I get an ObjectContext from my DbContext, it doesn't have members matching my tables, or any Where() methods.

Comment: @JeffDege see [How to convert DbSet in Entity framework to ObjectQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252096/how-to-convert-dbset-in-entity-framework-to-objectquery#11262713), something like: ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<foo>().Where("it.Price == @Price", new ObjectParameter[] { new ObjectParameter("Price", 5) });