# How to convert DbSet in Entity framework to ObjectQuery

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I am using CodeFirst approach and struck with an issue where I need to convert DbSet to ObjectQuery.
This is what I did for conversion.

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
ObjectSet<Request> objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Request>();
```

where db is the context inheriting from DbContext and Request is class.

So, when I try to call the method that expects ObjectQuery as ObjectQueryMethod(objectSet), it throws the following error.

"Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<>' and 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<>'"

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would you need to convert a DbSet to an ObjectQuery?

Comment: Provide more details - what is `ObjectQueryMethod`? Your current approach is correct. You cannot convert `DbSet` to `ObjectQuery`. You must create `ObjectSet` and use it instead of `DbSet`.

Comment: @Kittoes: I am trying to implement Advanced searching in JQGrid and ObjectQuery seems to be the right one to parse the parameters (filters) sent back to the server.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: It's just a method that expects ObjectQuery as a parameter (named as such) :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time. I figured out what I was missing, I need to pass the DbSet("Requests") to ObjectSet as ObjectSet<Request> objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Request>("Requests");

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer. Of course, it is possible to convert DbSet in Entity framework to ObjectQuery using the below lines of code.

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;  
ObjectSet<Request> objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Request>("Requests");
```

where,

- `db` - Context class inherting from `DbContext`.
- `Requests` - `DbSet<Request>` defined in Context class.
- `objectSet` - Can now be passed as `ObjectQuery`.

Comment: AFAIK you can leave the string out as parameter, which makes it less error-pron: `objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Request>();`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the correct answer 'inspiringmyself'; this is just to elaborate on your answer. I managed to do this with a generic type, so just to share it:

```
private List<T> GetByCustomCriteria<T>(string criteria) where T: class
{
  var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_myModelEntities).ObjectContext;
  //note: _myModelEntities is a DbContext in EF6.
  var objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
  return new List<T>(objectSet.Where(criteria));
 }
```

And I thought the above post could do with an example of what criteria to send so here's an example:

```
 //sample criteria for int field:
 var myClientById = GetByCustomCriteria<Client>("it.Id == 1");`

//sample criteria for string field, note the single quotes
var myClientByName = GetByCustomCriteria<Client>("it.Surname == 'Simpson'");
```