# Cannot implicitly convert dbSet to ObjectQuery

Tags: entity-framework, object, dbset

That is my code and it doesn't work like this, please help me !!!

```
public class BL: IBL, IDisposable
{

    private TradeSoftDBEntities entities;

    public List<Roles> TakeRoles()
    {

        if (entities == null) 
            entities = new TradeSoftDBEntities();

        ObjectQuery<Roles> roles = entities.Rolis;

        roles.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
```

Comment: This link might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252096/how-to-convert-dbset-in-entity-framework-to-objectquery