# How do i convert dbSet to ObjectQuery?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting an error on the following line of code.

```
ObjectQuery<NAME> names = dataEntities.NAMEs;
```

I am not sure how i can convert it to an ObjectQuery so I can actually use it.

Here is the rest of my code that I have so far which just populates my DataGrid

```
var query =
        from NAME in names
        where NAME.NameID == "student1"
        orderby NAME.MI
        select new { NAME.NameID, NAME.FirstName };

        userDataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: What is `dataEntities`? And why do you want an `ObjectQuery`?

Comment: @GertArnold I was following a Tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340709(v=vs.110).aspx Which is supposed to display information into my datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectSet` derives from `ObjectQuery`, so you can use object set like this,

```
ObjectSet<NAME> query = dataEntities.CreateObjectSet<NAME>();
```

For more details follow this [article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee473442%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252096/how-to-convert-dbset-in-entity-framework-to-objectquery) answer.

Comment: CreateObjectSet is not working for me. its telling me there is no definition for this.

Comment: here `dataEntities` is instance of your `context` class which derived from `dbcontext`.