# How to convert ObjectSet to DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I’m trying to create class from abstract one:

```
public class ManufacturerEntityService : BaseEntityService<Manufacturer>
{
    Entities entities = new Entities();

    protected override ObjectSet<Manufacturer> EntitySet
    {
        get { return entities.Manufacturers; }
    }

}
```

Error occurred:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<_21century.Models.Manufacturer>' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<_21century.Models.Manufacturer>'

In BaseEntityService i’ve used ObjectSet, cause DbSet doesn’t have SaveData method. The question is how to convert ObjectSet to DbSet? Is it possible or not? Any walkarounds? I have to pass DbContext obj there?

I’m newbie in creating mvc projects. Searching didn’t give any result. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Why are you using SaveData in your DbSet?  That should be done on the DbContext.

Comment: `ObjectSet.SaveData` doesn't exist. Is this some homebrewn extension method? But anyway, I'd always try to turn away from the legacy `ObjectSet` and replace it for the more developer-friendly `DbSet`. I don't know how much impact this would have on your code, but I'm sure it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here: [How to convert DbSet in Entity framework to ObjectQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252096/how-to-convert-dbset-in-entity-framework-to-objectquery)

```
public class ManufacturerEntityService : BaseEntityService<Manufacturer>
{
    Entities entities = new Entities();

    protected override ObjectSet<Manufacturer> EntitySet
    {
        get 
        { 
            ObjectContext objectContext = entities.ObjectContext;  
            return objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Manufacturer>("Manufacturers");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Better to mark as duplicate than to copy an answer, esp. when you don't copy it correctly (`entities.ObjectContext`). But while this answers the OP's direct question, it's probably not the best way to go.