# data type conversion error in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, type-conversion, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'd like to display data that are stored in a SQL server database in a data grid using C#. I tried to follow [this examples on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340709%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but have encountered a type conversion error. I am using Visual studio 2013.

I am connected to a SQL server, and created an ado.net data model named myEntity. The model contains several tables, one of them, Theater, is what I try to display on the screen.

Here is what I have:
On the MainWindow.xaml file I have

```
<Page x:Class="XYZ.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="theater List" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Data_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1"></DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

On the MainWindow.xaml.cs file I have:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Linq;

namespace XYZ
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        myEntities dataEntites = new myEntities();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Data_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                ObjectQuery<Theater> theaters = dataEntites.Theaters;

                var query = from theater in theaters
                            where theater.type == "Big"
                            orderby theater.id
                            select new
                            {
                                theater.State,
                                theater.City,
                                theater.Type, 
                                theater.Id, 
                                theater.Name,
                                theater.Capacity
                                 ...
                            };

                dataGrid1.ItemsSource = query.ToList();  
        }
    }
}
```

I encountered an error message on the line

```
ObjectQuery<Theater> theaters = dataEntites.Theaters;
```

Which states:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<XYZ.Theater>'`
>   to `'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<XYZ.Theater>'`

How could I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Well is there any reason you think you need an `ObjectQuery<Theater>`? I'd probably just declare the variable as being of type `IQueryable<Theater>`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11262713/5922757

Comment: Nothing particular, only try to follow the examples. I will give IQueryable<Theater> a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>` does not inherit from `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T>` and therefore an object of one class cannot be converted to another implicitly (expect the [implicit type conversion operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) would be overridden which is not the case).

So you simply have to change the type of the variable theaters from `ObjectQuery<Theater>` to `DbSet<Theater>`:

```
                DbSet<Theater> theaters = dataEntites.Theaters;

                var query = from theater in theaters 
                        where theater.type == "Big"
                        orderby theater.id
                        select new
                        {
                            theater.State,
                            theater.City,
                            theater.Type, 
                            theater.Id, 
                            theater.Name,
                            theater.Capacity
                             ...
                        };
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. For viewers, BbSet<T> uses System.Data.Entity namespace.